# Kotlin access activity on recyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerView and after click of card I would like to replace fragments in activity. The problem is I have no access to activity. Here is my code in adapter:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val itemsViewModel = mList[position]

    
    holder.tagImage.setImageResource(itemsViewModel.tagImage)
    holder.tagName.text = itemsViewModel.tagName
    holder.tagDescription.text = itemsViewModel.tagDescription

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

        Log.d(InTorry.TAG, itemsViewModel.tagName)

        val fragment = ProductsFragment()

        val transaction = activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
        transaction?.replace(R.id.homeFragmentsContainer, fragment)
        //transaction?.disallowAddToBackStack()
        transaction?.commit()

    }
}
```

The above replace code works in fragment but in adapter there is "activity?" error.

Kind Regards

Jack

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem.

1. **Using Context**

You can use the context from `holder.itemView` and cast it into an `Activity`.

This is probably the simplest way, however this can be problematic since a `Context` may represent an `Activity`, a `Service`, an `Application`, etc. in which case it may lead to a *`ClassCastException`* when used simply.

2. **Using Callback**

You can set up a callback from your Adapter to your `Activity` or `Fragment` and then replace your `Fragment`.

3. **Use JetPack Navigation**

This is my personal favorite as the latest versions allow you to access `NavController` from `Activity`, `Fragment` or any `View` in the hierarchy to navigate. This is just one of many benefits of using this library.

Here is a link to [Jetpack Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation).

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest and Safer way to solve this is my using Callback from your holder to activity. Below is the step by step process :

1. Decalare an Interface

   ```
   interface OnItemClick {
       fun onClick()
   }
   ```
2. Implement that interface in you Activity and put the desired code

   ```
   class MainActivity : OnItemClick {
   ...

       override onClick() {
       // Do whatever you want
       val fragment = ProductsFragment()
       val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
       transaction.replace(R.id.homeFragmentsContainer, fragment)
       transaction.commit()

       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a variable of that Interface type in you Adapter and in your **onBindViewHolder** method invoke that interface

   ```
   class MyAdapter(val listener : OnItemClick) {
   ... 


   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
       ...
       listener.onClick()

   }
   ```
4. Finally pass that interface to your Adapter from you Activity

   ```
   class MainActivity : OnItemClick {
       val adapter = MyAdapter(this)
   ...
   }
   ```

**NOTE : Please don't pass activity to context here and there you will get unexpected result and most probably a crash.**

Answer (score 0):

After watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqrpcWXBz14
I managed to do it this way

In Adapter

```
class TagsAdapter(var mList: List<TagsViewModel>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<TagsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var onItemClick: ((TagsViewModel) -> Unit)? = null//click listener STEP 1!!!

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TagsAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

            onItemClick?.invoke(itemsViewModel)//click listener STEP 2!!!

        }
    }
}
```

And in Fragment

```
class TagsFragment : Fragment() {
    
    private lateinit var tagsRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private var tagsArray = ArrayList<TagsViewModel>()
    private lateinit var adapter: TagsAdapter
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
        adapter = TagsAdapter(tagsArray)
        tagsRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        
        adapter.onItemClick = {//click listener STEP 3!!!
            
            val fragment = ProductsFragment()

            val transaction = activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
            transaction?.replace(R.id.homeFragmentsContainer, fragment)
            //transaction?.disallowAddToBackStack()
            transaction?.commit()
        }


    }
}
```

It looks very clean and easy. I don't know is a correct way but it works